# Ftp-клиент получает не весь запрашиваемый файл с сервера...

Tags: ftp, winsock, c++

Добрый день! Делаю, FTP-клиент... Скачиваю файл:

```
     char buff[65536];
using namespace std;
char sss[512];
struct hostent *host,*host2;
char addr[]="87.224.183.162";//ftp://162.183-224-87.telenet.ru/
fstream stream;
unsigned int file_size;
char file_name[256];
void reverse(char *str)
{
    char temp;
    int len;
    int i;

    len = strlen(str) - 1;

    for (i = 0; i <= len / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - i];
        str[len - i] = temp;
    }

    str[len + 1] = '\0';
}

SOCKET init_data(SOCKET s) {
    SOCKET ds;
    send(s,"PASV\r\n",strlen("PASV\r\n"),0);
    cout<<endl<<"C: PASV";
    recv(s,buff,1024,0);
    cout <<endl<< "S: "<< buff; ////выводим на экран полученную от сервера строку

    int a,b;
    char *tmp_char;
    tmp_char = strtok(buff,"(");
    tmp_char = strtok(NULL,"(");
    tmp_char = strtok(tmp_char, ")");
    int c,d,e,f;
    sscanf(tmp_char, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&c,&d,&e,&f,&a,&b);
    int len;
    sockaddr_in address;
    int result;

    int port = a*256 + b;

    ds = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);   ///addr - у меня глобальная переменная с адресом сервера
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    len = sizeof(address);
    result = connect(ds, (sockaddr *)&address, len);
    if (result == -1) {
           perror("oops: client");
        return -1;
    }

    return ds;
}

void sending(char a[],SOCKET ss){
    send(ss,a,strlen(a),0);
    cout<<"\nC: "<<a;
}

void readServ(SOCKET S) {
    for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
            buff[i]='\0';

    recv(S,buff,1024,0);
        cout << "S: "<<buff;
        Sleep(1000);
        //return 777;
}

int init_sock() {

    WSADATA WSAData;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&WSAData) != 0)
     {
          cout << "786";
          getch();
          exit(0);
     }

    SOCKET S;
    sockaddr_in address;
    S = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);// was 77.246.101.195    87.224.183.162    87.224.147.100    134.169.34.11 lin   
    address.sin_port = htons(21);
    if(address.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        host = NULL;
        host = gethostbyname(addr);

         if(host == NULL)
        {
//            MessageBox::Show("SERVER CONNECTION ERROR");
            exit(0);
        }
        memcpy(&address.sin_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    }

    int len;
    int result;
    len = sizeof(address);
    result = connect(S, (sockaddr *)&address, len);
    if (result == -1) 
    {
        cout << "87698";
        getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "Connection Estabilished!\n";
    readServ(S);
 return S;

}

char *getdata(SOCKET ds){
    char file[65536];
    for(int i=0; i<65536; i++)
        file[i]='\0';
    recv(ds, file,sizeof(file),0);
    closesocket(ds); 
    return file;
}

int getfile(SOCKET ds){
    char *tmp_char;
        tmp_char = strtok(buff,"\r\n");
    char t[256];
    memset(t,'\0',sizeof(t));
    strcpy(t, tmp_char);
    int i=44, u=0;
    char n[256];
    memset(n,'\0',sizeof(n));
    while(t[i]!='\0'){
        n[u]=t[i];
        i++; u++;
    }
    u-=8; i=0;
    char e[256];
    memset(e,'\0', sizeof(e));
    while(n[u]!='('){
        e[i]=n[u];
        i++; u--;
    }
    reverse(e);
    file_size=atoi(e);
    int n_len=u-1;
    for(int i=0; i<n_len;i++)
            file_name[i]=n[i];

    stream.open(file_name,ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    if(!stream){
        cout<<"Error open\n";
        getch();
        return 0;
    }

    char file[512];
    memset(file,'\0',65536);
    int num=0;
    unsigned int k=0;

    while( num=recv(ds, &file[0], strlen(file),0) || k < file_size){
        if(num<0){
            cout<<"Error";
            printf(" %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
        k+=strlen(file);
        stream<<file;
        memset(file,'\0',sizeof(file));
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Recieved "<<k<<" bytes\n";
    }

    closesocket(ds);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0,"");

    SOCKET DATA;
    SOCKET S;
    S = init_sock();

    /*char str1[512];
    sprintf(str1,"QUIT\r\n");

    sending(str1,S);
    readServ(S);*/

    char name[64] = "anonymous";
    char str[512];
    sprintf(str,"USER %s\r\n",name);

    sending(str,S);
    readServ(S);

    char pass[64] = "anonymous";
    sprintf(str,"PASS %s\r\n",pass);

    sending(str,S);
    readServ(S);

    DATA=init_data(S);

    strcpy(pass,"/");
    sending("LIST\r\n",S);
    Sleep(2000);
    readServ(S);//Ответ

    char file[65536];
    strcpy(file, getdata(DATA));//Список
    cout<<file<<endl;//Ответ -список

    sending("TYPE I\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    sending("CWD ! ! Новинки КИНО\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    sending("CWD Шеф (комедия) [2012]\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    Sleep(2000);

    DATA=init_data(S);
    sending("LIST\r\n",S);
    Sleep(2000);
    readServ(S);
    strcpy(file, getdata(DATA));//Список
    cout<<file<<endl;//Ответ -список
    //-------------------------------------------------Файл!!!

    DATA=init_data(S);
    sending("RETR Обложка.jpg\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    Sleep(2000);
    getfile(DATA);

    closesocket(S);  ///закрытие соединения
    WSACleanup();

    stream.close();
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Файлы приходят не полностью... Иногда полностью... Маленькие приходят, (относительно маленькие 65 байт, 111 байт). Большие как-то странно приходят(кусками, спрева кусок начала, затем через сколько-то байт, а потом вообще ничего не приходит...). Будто сервер шлет Огромный кусок, а мой клиент вырывает из этого куска сколько влазит в переменную... Может размер отправляемого куска можно как-то установить? У меня FTP pasv...

Comment: @Alerr, вот тут

     while(num=recv(ds, &file[0], sizeof(file),0)!=-1){

`num=recv(ds, &file[0], sizeof(file),0)` надо в скобочки заключить.

Comment: while((num=recv(ds, &file[0], sizeof(file),0))!=-1) сделал, всё равно ничего не изменилось...

Comment: @alexlz, приём 0 байт означает только приём 0 байт, а конец файла это только в том случае, если общее количество принятого равно длине файла (это как раз из тех вещей, которые я имел в виду говоря про `read()` когда-то, и любой сокетовед обязан это знать, несмотря на то, что написано в `man recv(2)`)

Comment: @Alerr, ну, понятно же, что на самом деле надо писать

    while(num=recv(ds, file, sizeof(file),0) {
        if(num<0){
            cout<<"Error";
        ....

если file - это массив размещенный в функции (или статический). Вы бы значимые куски кода (объявление переменных, отведение памяти) тоже привели, тогда понятней было бы, что Вы думаете, а что делаете.

--

Кстати, передача файла по сокету ds завершается закрытие сокета со стороны передатчика? Или конец передачи определяется как-то по другому?

Что RFC по FTP говорит на этот счет? Просто читать лень.

Comment: @klopp что ещё за приём 0 байт при блокирующем чтении?

@Alerr запустите wireshark и посмотрите, что идёт по портам 20 (ftp-data) и 21.
 У Вашей программы и у браузера.

Comment: А там блок? Sossy, в голову не пришло, что кто-то может заниматься такой ерундой :)

Comment: Функция int getfile(SOCKET ds);

Вместо strlen(file) ставьте константу 512 или sizeof(). У меня strlen(file) выдаёт 542, а не 512.

Посмотрите в этой команде stream<<file;
Каким образом 'stream' может определить размер 'file'?

У file в первых сисволах может быть 0. 

Сделайте проверку

if(num<=0){"error"}else{
for(int i=0; i < num; i++){ std::cout << file[i];}
}

Comment: однажды в софте очень уважаемой конторы в которой я работал я встретил ошибку(несоответствие rfc) которая формулируется так - по ошибке реализован ftp client. подумайте еще раз, надо или нет писать свою имплиментацию.

Comment: Кстати, пытаюсь оттранслировать. g++ ругается на getdata. Эта функция возвращает локальный буффер file. Так делать не надо.

Comment: Почему? что плохого?

Comment: > num=recv(ds, &file[0], strlen(file),0) || k < file_size 

Это условие, из-за приоритета опретаторов, становится следующим: 

> ((num=recv(ds, &file[0], strlen(file),0)) || k) < file_size 

это явно не то, условие, которое вы проверяли.

Comment: То, что память выделяется во фрейме стека. А стек при выходе из функции (getdata) освобождается, т.е. указатель смещается вверх. И, если кому-то потребуется стек (возможно strcpy), то это место может быть занято и затёрто.

Кроме того, если у Вас данные двоичные, то strcpy не подходит -- прекратит работу при встрече первого нуля.

Comment: затем, вы неправильно считаете k, о чем вам уже говорили. в цикле должно быть
>k += num > 0? num : 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы внимательно слушали, то всё получилось бы.
[image]

Код у вас рабочий. 
Только запись принятых данных выполняется неправильно.

---

Вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#ifndef _WINSOCKAPI_ 
#include <winsock2.h>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")




char buff[65536];
using namespace std;
char sss[512];
struct hostent *host,*host2;
char addr[]="87.224.183.162";//ftp://162.183-224-87.telenet.ru/
std::fstream stream;
unsigned int file_size;
char file_name[256];
void reverse(char *str)
{
    char temp;
    int len;
    int i;

    len = strlen(str) - 1;

    for (i = 0; i <= len / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - i];
        str[len - i] = temp;
    }

    str[len + 1] = '\0';
}

SOCKET init_data(SOCKET s) {
    SOCKET ds;
    send(s,"PASV\r\n",strlen("PASV\r\n"),0);
    cout<<endl<<"C: PASV";
    recv(s,buff,1024,0);
    cout <<endl<< "S: "<< buff; ////выводим на экран полученную от сервера строку

    int a,b;
    char *tmp_char;
    tmp_char = strtok(buff,"(");
    tmp_char = strtok(NULL,"(");
    tmp_char = strtok(tmp_char, ")");
    int c,d,e,f;
    sscanf(tmp_char, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&c,&d,&e,&f,&a,&b);
    int len;
    sockaddr_in address;
    int result;

    int port = a*256 + b;

    ds = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);   ///addr - у меня глобальная переменная с адресом сервера
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    len = sizeof(address);
    result = connect(ds, (sockaddr *)&address, len);
    if (result == -1) {
           perror("oops: client");
        return -1;
    }

    return ds;
}

void sending(char a[],SOCKET ss){
    send(ss,a,strlen(a),0);
    cout<<"\nC: "<<a;
}

void readServ(SOCKET S) {
    for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
            buff[i]='\0';

    recv(S,buff,1024,0);
        cout << "S: "<<buff;
        Sleep(1000);
        //return 777;
}

int init_sock() {

    WSADATA WSAData;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&WSAData) != 0)
     {
          cout << "786";
         // getch();
         // exit(0);
     }

    SOCKET S;
    sockaddr_in address;
    S = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);// was 77.246.101.195    87.224.183.162    87.224.147.100    134.169.34.11 lin   
    address.sin_port = htons(21);
    if(address.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        host = NULL;
        host = gethostbyname(addr);

         if(host == NULL)
        {
//            MessageBox::Show("SERVER CONNECTION ERROR");
            exit(0);
        }
        memcpy(&address.sin_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    }

    int len;
    int result;
    len = sizeof(address);
    result = connect(S, (sockaddr *)&address, len);
    if (result == -1) 
    {
        cout << "87698";
//        getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "Connection Estabilished!\n";
    readServ(S);
 return S;

}

char *getdata(SOCKET ds){
    char file[65536];
    for(int i=0; i<65536; i++)
        file[i]='\0';
    recv(ds, file,sizeof(file),0);
    closesocket(ds); 
    return file;
}

int getfile(SOCKET ds){
    char *tmp_char;
        tmp_char = strtok(buff,"\r\n");
    char t[256];
    memset(t,'\0',sizeof(t));
    strcpy(t, tmp_char);
    int i=44, u=0;
    char n[256];
    memset(n,'\0',sizeof(n));
    while(t[i]!='\0'){
        n[u]=t[i];
        i++; u++;
    }
    u-=8; i=0;
    char e[256];
    memset(e,'\0', sizeof(e));
    while(n[u]!='('){
        e[i]=n[u];
        i++; u--;
    }
    reverse(e);
    file_size=atoi(e);
    int n_len=u-1;
    for(int i=0; i<n_len;i++)
            file_name[i]=n[i];

    stream.open(file_name,ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    if(!stream){
        cout<<"Error open\n";
//        getch();
        return 0;
    }

    char file[4096];
    int num=0;
    unsigned int k=0;
int размер_файла=0;
    while( num=recv(ds, file, 4096,0)){
        if(num<0){
            cout<<"Error";
            printf(" %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

// записывается сразу в файл
stream.write(file,num);
  размер_файла+=num;
cout<<"Recieved "<< num <<" bytes\n";
Sleep(5);
}

std::cout<<"\nRecieved байт"<< размер_файла;
closesocket(ds);
return 1;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0,"");

    SOCKET DATA;
    SOCKET S;
    S = init_sock();

    /*char str1[512];
    sprintf(str1,"QUIT\r\n");

    sending(str1,S);
    readServ(S);*/

    char name[64] = "anonymous";
    char str[512];
    sprintf(str,"USER %s\r\n",name);

    sending(str,S);
    readServ(S);

    char pass[64] = "anonymous";
    sprintf(str,"PASS %s\r\n",pass);

    sending(str,S);
    readServ(S);

    DATA=init_data(S);

    strcpy(pass,"/");
    sending("LIST\r\n",S);
    Sleep(444);
    readServ(S);//Ответ

    char file[65536];
    strcpy(file, getdata(DATA));//Список
    cout<<file<<endl;//Ответ -список

    sending("TYPE I\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    sending("CWD ! ! Новинки КИНО\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    sending("CWD Шеф (комедия) [2012]\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    Sleep(444);

    DATA=init_data(S);
    sending("LIST\r\n",S);
    Sleep(444);
    readServ(S);
    strcpy(file, getdata(DATA));//Список
    cout<<file<<endl;//Ответ -список
    //-------------------------------------------------Файл!!!

    DATA=init_data(S);
    sending("RETR Обложка.jpg\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    Sleep(444);
    getfile(DATA);

    closesocket(S);  ///закрытие соединения
    WSACleanup();

    stream.close();
//    getch();


std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вывел ошибка recv 0.

Comment: А вы уверены что у вас само соединение активно?
recv
"If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero." - "Если соединение закрылось, то возвращаемое значение 0."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Уверен. Смотрите, когда я принимал в file[65536], как бы начало файла приходило, середина и... ближе к концу... Теперь беру file[512] вроде ничего не приходит... При file[65536] как бы передавался сервером весь файл, но я получал только какие-то куски, а потом 0... Я после list, после приема списка, закрываю сокет... А потом снова pasv и создаю новый для файла.

Comment: gracefully -- изящно, элегантно. Это нормальное закрытие соединения.

Comment: > Я после list, после приема списка, закрываю сокет...

Управляющий сокет нельзя закрывать до окончательного закрытия соединения. Как только вы его закроете, то и получите connection has been gracefully closed от сервера.

Comment: Не, не управляющий закрываю, а datasocket.

Comment: а файл какого размера запрашиваете?

Comment: да не важно какого размера, получил ошибку 10054
WSAECONNRESET
Connection reset by peer. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt (Windows Sockets) for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket.) This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a fa...

Comment: Получилось... ААААА manking, где, в каком месте была ошибка??? тыкните пальцем? Спасибо вам!

Comment: @Alerr 

Вы в функцию recv() передаете размер буфера равный 0.
strlen(file) считает размер файла до первого нулевого символа. А так как вы массив 'file' полностью заполняете тер-нулями, то strlen возвращает 0, и recv() возвращает ошибку.

Затем вы помещаете бинарный массив 'file' в поток stream, без указания размера этого массива.
Проще использовать std::string заполняя его методом append(массив,'размер'). Где 'размер' это то что возвращает recv().
Затем уже готовую строку std::string наполненую бинарными данными(изображением) можно записать в файл.

Comment: А вот это-то 

    memset(file,'\0',4096);

зачем ??? Можно ведь

    file[num] = 0; // num это количество прочитанных байт

после проверки 

    if(num<0){
      cout<<"Error";
      printf(" %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
      break;
    }

Идея же с хранением получаемого файла в string на мой взгляд не слишком хорошая.

Comment: @avp
Если честно там в коде очень много того, что мне очень непонятно.
Сами memset бессмысленны, так как буфер всё равно перезаписывается и есть точный размер.

Вообще, в std::string бинарные данные я обычно храню. 
Проблем нет если добавлять данные через append(), и не использовать перегруженные операторы.
А как лучше, в std::vector<char> или еще где то?

Comment: @manking, да просто файл может быть большой, лучше его по мере поступления в файл записывать.

Даже если потом весь его надо вернуть, как string. Просто каждый append (куска большего, чем разница между str.size() и str.capacity())  будет на самом деле делать копию  str и в конце чтения память, занимаемая данными вообще удвоится.

Лучше записать в файл (все равно в памяти (файловом кэше) осядет), а потом уже, зная размер, прочесть этот файл в string достаточного  размера.

Это если решились использовать string, но на мой вкус тут больше подойдет тривиальный char \* и malloc (или new).